# sumif if the criteria is text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In column A I have below data set.

```
A1 : TR029A/TR029B
A2 : TR028A/TR028B
A3 : TR035A/TR035B
A4 : TR035A
A5 : TR029A
A6 : TR035A/TR035B
```

column B values as below

```
B1 : 5
B2 : 3
B3 : 4
B4 : 2
B5 : 7
B6 : 4
```

I want `SUMIF`  separately using drop down as `TR029A` so on and on.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the drop down in cell `D1` then use this formula -

`=IF(D1 = "", "", SUMIF(A:A,"*"&D1&"*",B:B))`

N.B. - Thanks @Solar Mike for the suggestion.

Comment: Thanks  Ahamed.Its worked.But I have a little concern further.When criteria (D1) blank the formula calculate all the values in column B.any advise

Comment: Then edit  to =if(D1="","",SUMIF(A:A,"*"&D1&"*",B:B))